# WCF Service's JSON string response to Ajax POST request is not accepted. Method always goes to error.

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, json, ajax

I have written a WCF service which in theory, should accept a JSON object from Ajax and return true or false as a response to indicate the JSON object was accepted from service and sent to the database.
This is how the interface is implemented in IService

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method ="POST",ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json,UriTemplate ="InsertPatient")]
String InsertPatient(Patient PatientObj);
```

The contract is implemented as follows

```
public String InsertPatient(Patient PatientObj)
    {
        PatientContext pat = new PatientContext();
        Boolean boolObj = new Boolean();
        string JsonString = "";

        if (pat.Patients.Where(x => x.Username == PatientObj.Username).Any())
        {
            // Username already taken;                
            boolObj = false; 
            JsonString =JsonConvert.ToString(boolObj);
            return JsonString; 
        }
        else
        {   //Initiate to add user to login table
            Login log = new Login();
            log.Username = PatientObj.Username;
            log.Password = PatientObj.Password;
            log.User_Type = PatientObj.User_Type;
            if (InsertLogin(log)) //if login added 
            {
                pat.Patients.Add(PatientObj);  //add user to patient table
                pat.SaveChanges();

                boolObj = true;
                JsonString = JsonConvert.ToString(boolObj);
                return JsonString;
            }
            else //login was not added
            {
                boolObj = false;
                JsonString = JsonConvert.ToString(boolObj);
                return JsonString;
            }
        }

    }
```

and finally the Ajax script is implemented as follows

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").submit(function () {
            var L_Username = $("#UN").val();
            var L_User_Type = "patient";
            var L_Name = $("#name").val();
            var L_Birthday = $("#bday").val();
            var L_Gender = $("input[name='optradio']:checked").val();
            var L_Contact = $("#cNo").val();
            var L_Password = $("#password").val();
            var L_Address = $("#adress").val();

            var jsondata = {
                Username: L_Username,
                User_Type: L_User_Type,
                Address: L_Address,
                Birthday: L_Birthday,
                Contact: L_Contact,
                Gender: L_Gender,
                Name: L_Name,
                Password: L_Password
            };
            console.log(JSON.stringify(jsondata));

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:50709/Service1.svc/rest/InsertPatient",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(jsondata),                
                success: function (resultdata) {                       
                        alert("inserted");                      
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert("Something went wrong");
                }
            });
        });

    }); 
</script>
```

When I test this through POST-man , I get the correct response as true or false. But when I run this from the website itself. Ajax always throw the error alert, but the values get successfully added to the tables.

What am I doing wrong , please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post what the error e is?

Comment: @Blast_dan in the error section when i use
alert(e.responseText); and run the function , it says "Undefined"